# Incorrect percentage from integers

Tags: java

My code is giving me `44400.0%`.  I've messed with it a bunch, but this is the closest I've gotten to the correct answer.  I'm only allowed to change things on the line where I've defined the temp array and below.  When I try to divide more I lose significant digits, as I need three fours as part of the percentage.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ArrayElements90OrMore 
{
    public static void main( String [] args ) 
    {
        int [] array = { 91, 82, 73, 94, 35, 96, 90, 89, 65 };
        DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat( "#0.0%" );

        System.out.print( "The elements are " );
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
            System.out.print( array[i] + " " );
        System.out.println( );

        System.out.println( "The percentage of elements 90 or greater is "
                            + percent.format( percent90OrMore( array ) ) );
    }

    public static int percent90OrMore( int [] temp ) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {
            if ( temp[i] >= 90 ) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return  ( count * 1000 ) / ( temp.length );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should multiply by 100 to get the percentage of some fraction :

```
return  ( count * 100 ) / temp.length;
```

However, if you are already using `percent.format` to display the fraction as percentage, you should simply return the fraction :

```
return  (double) count / temp.length;
```

Note that in this case `percent90OrMore` must return a float or a double. Otherwise you'll always get either 0 or 1.

```
  public static double percent90OrMore (int[] temp)
  {
      int count = 0;
      for ( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ )
      {
          if ( temp[i] >= 90 )
          {
              count++;
          }
      }   
      return  (double)count/temp.length;
  }
```

Comment: That's the thing that's really bugging me.  I'm not supposed to change the first part and it won't accept a double.  It'd be easy if it would accept a double.

Comment: @dsorenson `percent.format()` does accept double. Which part can't you change? You only have to change `percent90OrMore`

Comment: I can't change anything through the last print statement.  

When I use this line of code:   return ( ( double ) count * 100 ) / temp.length;  
  
I get this error:   
  
ArrayElements90OrMore.java:35: error: possible loss of precision
return ( ( double ) count * 100 ) / temp.length;  
                                    ^  
  required: int  
  found:    double  
1 error

Comment: `percent90OrMore` must return double or float.

Comment: I know it has to I just don't know how to get one in there.  

With this line:  
  
      return ( double ) count / temp.length;

I get an error every time.

Comment: @dsorenson Have you tried the version of `percent90OrMore` that appears in my answer, or are you not allowed to make those changes?

Comment: Thank you sooo much.  I glanced over the change of the method to return a double.  I thought it had to be an int and so I was trying everything else I could possibly think of.  I just needed to change public static int to public static double.  I had it as a double once but I messed up by trying to make a double array while returning a double and it messed the whole thing up which got me confused.

Answer (score 0):

Odd way if you don't want to change method return type is:

```
System.out.println( "The percentage of elements 90 or greater is "
                        + percent.format( percent90OrMore( array ) * 1000.0d / ( (double) temp.length ) ) );
```

And change your method as below:

```
public static int percent90OrMore( int [] temp ) {
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {
        if ( temp[i] >= 90 ) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```